# Please help identify this font similar to Venus Rising

Tags: fonts, font-identification, sans-serif

I used this font a few years ago, but I have lost the source docx file. I suppose it is a free font, since I used LibreOffice on Linux while creating this title plate with it.

I already have tried sites WhatTheFont!, Identifont, "What Font is" and Fontspring Matcherator, but they couldn't identify the font.

[image]